# Whats wrong with my javascript loop returning xml?

Tags: javascript, xml

I have something wrong with my loop as it is returning all the name, link, image and content  in one go instead of looping through evey event individually

```js
var items=xml.getElementsByTagName('event').length;
//alert(items);
var name, link, image, content;

for (var i = 0; i < items; i++) {
    //alert('in the loop');
    name = $(xml).find('name').text();
    link = $(xml).find('url').text();
    image = $(xml).find('image').text();
    content = $(xml).find('content').text();

    $('#headername')
    .append('<h3>' + name + '</h3><br /><img src="' + image + '" alt="' + name +'" width="100%"><br /><p>' + content 
            + '</p><h4>Read more at: </h4><a rel="external" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-icon="back" onclick="doOpen(&#39;' + link + '&#39;, &#39;_blank&#39;);">' +name +'</a><br />' );


}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "returning"? How is the result you got different from expected?

Comment: As there are currently 3 'events' ,it is returning the var name + name + name + link + link + link etc.
Instead of name + link + image + content + name + link + image + content etc

Comment: Oh, I see. The problem is that `$(xml).find('el')` returns the first element found every time through the loop -- it know that you want the nth one partway through your loop.

Comment: Could you give me an example how it should be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that $(xml).find('el') returns the first element found every time through the loop, whereas you want the nth one on the nth iteration.

Try this instead:

```
for (var i = 0; i < items; i++) {
    name = $(xml).find('name').eq(i).text();
    //                        ^^^^^^
    // ...
}
```

Note also that it's not a very good idea to build HTML using `+`, since the data could contain HTML characters. They should be escaped with `escape`:

```
.append('<h3>' + escape(name) +  /* ... */ );
```

Comment: Cameron, where does the eq come from? I am a bit confused now, sorry

Comment: @Johann: From jQuery, which I assumed (perhaps incorrectly) that you were using because of the `$` function. I guess I could be clearer: Your loop is fine, except that instead of getting the first name/image/url elements on the first iteration of the loop, and the second set on the second iteration, etc., you get the first elements (that's what `find` does) on *every* iteration :-) Does that help?

Comment: Yes, that bit is exactly whats happening. And I kid of understand what your example shows, but I am new to jquery and Javascript, so the .eq threw me completely off :( Its probably simple, but for me frustrating as I have been struggling for 2 days with this :(

Comment: @Johann: I misspoke. `find` returns *all* of the elements that match the selector (in an array). `text()` concatenates the text of all of them together. What you want is to select a single element from the returned array -- the `i`th one. `eq` does exactly that -- it simply selects the element with the given index from the array (and turns it into a jQuery element). You can play with this stuff in your browser's console to see what's going on (F12 in Chrome): `$('<xml><a>a</a><a>b</a></xml>').find('a').eq(1).text()` => `"b"`.

Comment: YAY!  That worked a charm! Thanks for explaining and helping.